# Kill a process tree from task scheduled windows batch file

Tags: windows, process, scheduled-tasks, kill, taskkill

I have created a Windows Task that runs on Admin account with highest privileges that runs a batch file every minute.

This batch file will execute a PHP script to retrieve a webpage , after which it checks if no page or wrong content is returned.

If the result is negative then the batch routine kills the httpd process and its children using taskkill (I am currently dealing with a PHP hang causing the Apache Http process to hang as well).

This entire process works perfectly when executed while logged onto the machine as admin. However when executing as a task (and despite admin privileges) the process does NOT get killed. There is no event or debug entry.

So my question is why is task kill unable to kill the process, how can I get more info and what alternatives exist?

Comment: Does not really answer the question I'm afraid